# Find Hibernate objects without many to many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to find all the products that do not contain a specific allergen using Hibernate.

Here is the SQL used to create the database tables:

```
CREATE TABLE ALLERGEN (id integer IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, name varchar(20), UNIQUE (id), UNIQUE(name));
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (id integer IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, name varchar(20), UNIQUE (id), UNIQUE(name));
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_ALLERGEN (product_id integer, allergen_id integer, UNIQUE (product_id, allergen_id), FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES PRODUCT (id), FOREIGN KEY (allergen_id) REFERENCES ALLERGEN (id));
```

Here are the Hibernate annotated Java classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ALLERGEN")
class Allergen {

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    // ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "allergen_id")})
    private final Set<Allergen> allergens = new HashSet<>();

    // ...
}
```

This SQL appears to give me the result I want, but I don't see how to represent it using Hibernate criteria.

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PRODUCT_ALLERGEN WHERE product_id = PRODUCT.id AND allergen_id = 0) = 0;
```

Comment: Do you want the query in HQL, or using the Criteria API?

Comment: I was looking for the solution in Criteria API, but an equivalent in HQL would be of interest too.

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-query-examples-hql/

Answer (score 1):

With the Criteria API you should be able to get all Product without Allergens by creating a left join from Product to Allergen and checking if it is null:

```
final CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<Product> c = builder.createQuery(Product.class);
final Root<Product> root = c.from(Product.class);
Join<Product, Allergen> allergenJoin = root.join("allergens", JoinType.LEFT);
c.where(builder.isNull(allergenJoin));
c.select(root);
List<Product> = entityManager.createQuery(c).getResultList();
```

Note: I didn't include where you get the EntityManager from. Usually I use injection for that, but there are other methods like using a factory.

Comment: Realised that this answer is correct, but that my question was ambiguous. I meant "find the products that don't contain a specific allergen." not "find the products that don't contain any allergens.".

Answer (score 0):

This code uses JPQL to get the products without a specific allergen.

```
List<Product> results = manager.createQuery(
        "SELECT p from Product AS p WHERE (SELECT COUNT(a) FROM p.allergens a WHERE a.name = :an) = 0",
        Product.class)
    .setParameter("an", "nuts")
    .getResultList();
```